# How to play MP3 files in C?

Tags: c, mp3

I'm looking for the easiest way to play a MP3 file in C. I am looking for either a library, in which I could just call the function on the filename, or an executable that will just run and quit. Please suggest.

Comment: What kind of license should this library have? I'd guess there are a couple of GPL ones (although the mp3 format/algorithm always has/had it's license issues) but these might not fit your project. Also: windows/osx/linux?

Answer (score 27):

Using [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/download/) (cross platform), this should be as simple as this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "inc/fmod.h"

FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;

int main ()
{
   // init FMOD sound system
   FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

   // load and play mp3
   handle=FSOUND_Sample_Load (0,"my.mp3",0, 0, 0);
   FSOUND_PlaySound (0,handle);

   // wait until the users hits a key to end the app
   while (!_kbhit())
   {
   }

   // clean up
   FSOUND_Sample_Free (handle);
   FSOUND_Close();
}
```

As a side note, I'd suggest you using C++ over C.

Answer (score 5):

The [BASS DLL](http://www.un4seen.com/) is really easy to use and will probably do what you need. It is only free for non-commercial use though.

If you need more control, you will need a codec (I prefer [libMad](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/)) and some sound output API like DirectSound on Windows or ALSA or Linux (or whatever Linux guys use for sound this week)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is "the easiest way", but you could have a look at SDL (along with SDL_sound).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows or OSX, I recommend BASS (http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html)

You can download the library and look at code sample to get started. The "contest" example in C directory is a good start point.

Answer (score 2):

On Win32, you don't need any library.
Use standard Win32 api (mp3 is native)

See on Adv. Win32 api newsgroup :
news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
where it 's a FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

If u can use C++ and if u are working on windows platform than use
[WMp3](http://www.inet.hr/~zcindori/mp3class/)

That Library is easy to work with and let you play, pause, seek on mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

> alternatively something someone's already written that will just run and quit.

You can use [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/) (or the fixed point port of it, [mpg321](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net/))

```
mpg123 <mp3file>
```

will play an mp3 file and quit.

Answer (score 0):

[mpg123](http://www.mpg123.org/) has a generic remote interface that you access by starting the executable with the -R option. You can then send commands (such as load, pause etc) over a fifo pipe or to stdin of the subprocess. If nothing else it's easy to debug and test manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://code4k.blogspot.com/2010/05/playing-mp3-in-c-using-plain-windows.html

This website has a zip in which you can view how this person generated the code for an mp3 player.

You can also check out: 
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directshow/article.php/c19079/Simple-C-MP3-Player-Class.htm

or

http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Control/Play-MP3-File-VC-Sample-Player.htm