# How to play mp3 file in c++?

Tags: c++, mp3

I'm looking for the easiest way to play an MP3 file in C++. Either a library I could use and just call the function, given the filename, or alternatively something someone has already written that will just run and quit.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428884/how-to-play-mp3-files-in-c

Answer (score 4):

What platform are you on? You can check these out:

In case of windows/linux:
[FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download)

In case you are programming only on windows/mac osx:
[BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/)

I would also look for some native APIs in Windows (if you are developing on that platform).
HTH,
Sriram

Answer (score 3):

Qt comes to the rescue (again). The documentation even comes with demo code on how to implement a media player. It can play videos as well, btw.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/demos-qmediaplayer.html

Works on all platform and with the same syntax = WIN.