# Is there any easy way to play a mp3 file

Tags: c++, qt, open-source, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play mp3 file in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732278/how-to-play-mp3-file-in-c)

Hi,

I am doing a project which demands the functions of mp3 player. There is no need of giant, full pledged solution, all I want is just "play","pause","stop". I found some libs which are libmad,lame.But, I can't find any example for them. If anybody shed a light on this, I will be thankful to them.
   Or Is there any way in Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Phonon component in Qt 4.
Not sure about Window, but in Ubuntu it can play pretty much every format whose codec is available.
You might look into Qt Docs at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-overview.html

Comment: Thank you, it playes superb. This is the exact solution I need.